# Retrieving the time value where the datatype is time(1)

Tags: c#, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2, timespan

In one of my windows application I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. Where there is a column with datatype `time(1)`.

I have a dummy value in that column lets say `09:00:00` which is in the format `HH:mm:ss`.

Now when I am retrieving the same value in the code and storing it into grid. I use the following code.

```
VSFlexShift.set_TextMatrix(i, 2, objShiftMasterDTO.SHIFT_START.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
```

But I get an error

> Input string was not in a correct format

When I store the date value for ex:

```
Column: date 
datatype: DateTime 
Value: 2015-11-30 15:05:01.120
```

When I tried to retrieve it in code

```
 VSFlexHoliday.set_TextMatrix(i, 3, objHolidayMasterDTO.HOLIDAY_DATE.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

This is returned: `30/11/2015`.

Now I need to get the time format what I have mentioned first as `9:00:00`. How to get it? Any help appreciated.

Comment: how did you map the `time` property to the `DateTime` of the DTO?

Comment: `TimeSpan _SHIFT_START;`

Comment: What is the value of the `TimeSpan _SHIFT_START` at runtime?

Comment: Should the value of the `timespan` not be `9:00:00`? Why is it `TimeSpan.MaxValue`?

Comment: WEll i am really confused with the things going around. Is there any ways that the code can be changed to get the proper output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [`time` mapped with `TimeSpan`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) in CLR side, `TimeSpan` formatting is *little* bit different than `DateTime` formatting.

From Custom TimeSpan Format Strings;

> The custom `TimeSpan` format specifiers do not include placeholder
>   separator symbols, such as the symbols that separate days from hours,
>   hours from minutes, or seconds from fractional seconds. Instead, these
>   symbols must be included in the custom format string as string
>   literals. For example, `"dd\.hh\:mm"` defines a period (`.`) as the
>   separator between days and hours, and a colon (`:`) as the separator
>   between hours and minutes.

That's why you need to use `\:` for separators and need to use [`hh` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#hhSpecifier) since `TimeSpan` does not have `HH` specifier as a custom specifier.

```
VSFlexShift.set_TextMatrix(i, 2, objShiftMasterDTO.SHIFT_START.ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss"));
```

or

```
VSFlexShift.set_TextMatrix(i, 2, objShiftMasterDTO.SHIFT_START.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"));
```

Further reading:

- [Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)